# Angular2 Typescript how to retrieve an array from inside an object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object, typescript

When I do console.log of the following:

```
console.log(this.categories);
```

I get this structure:

[image]

which was created from this json from the api:

```
[
  {
  "id":"dff0bb3e-889f-43e6-b955-52cc7203952f",
  "name":"Wood",
  "category_types":[
     {
        "id":"49b31f43-d98d-43c8-9798-088ec6914fe5",
        "name":"Solid"
     },
     {
        "id":"8592716a-ffd5-4e97-ba9e-6a64ba6e48f1",
        "name":"Engineered"
     }
  ]
  },
  {
  "id":"6b2b6914-6c64-4389-a327-be3f08fd066d",
  "name":"Carpet",
  "category_types":[
     {
        "id":"0e2c8473-90fb-4806-a6e7-2389eeb0f9e4",
        "name":"Loop pile"
     },
     {
        "id":"3c762653-4f0d-42d2-a84e-133c7051c95b",
        "name":"Cut pile"
     },
     {
        "id":"0997d4dc-e886-46ef-83b4-d90c4fb72553",
        "name":"Cut \u0026 loop pile"
     }
  ]
  }
]
```

Given that I have the value 'Wood' in a string variable called `value`, how do I get hold of the category_types array for the Wood object?

```
console.log(this.categories[value]);
```

returns undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find object that has name of 'Wood', then get `category_types`. `Array.prototype.find`  returns first value that meets the condition in the provided test function. In your case, it could look like this:

```
this.categories.find(value => value.name === 'Wood').category_types
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter`:

```
let wood = this.categories.filter(category => {
  return category.name === "Wood";
})[0];
```

This will filter your categories to retrieve the ones with name wood, then you take the first one. If you didn't find anything with `name === "Wood"` in your array, then it will be `undefined`.

Comment: This is why there is `find` method.

Comment: @estus I agree, but `find` seems to be absent in some cases, I can't use it in my current angular project, maybe because of es5.