# Angular2 & Typescript - Property name does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular, object, typescript

The suggested answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095483/angular2-typescript-how-to-retrieve-an-array-from-inside-an-object) using find does not work in Typescript, it cannot compile. I've looked at other similar questions, but they all seem a little different (context) in some way.

This is the array:

```
categories: Category[] = [];
```

This is Category object:

```
export class Category{
  constructor(
    id: string,
    name: string,
    category_types: Object[]
  ) {}
}
```

and I am trying to find like this (value is a string, eg 'Wood'):

```
let a = this.categories.find(v => v.name === value);
```

It says Property name does not exist on type 'Category'.

Comment: can you share the code where you set the values for categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your class `Category` does not have any properties. You can define [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) to create properties directly out of constructor parameters:

```
export class Category{
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public category_types: Object[]
  ) {}
}
```

Now all the parameters of `Category` are also its public properties.